# Problem with Raspberry Pi 3 model B Ubuntu-Mate Error "Temporary Failure resolving "ports.ubuntu.com"

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I have downloaded and installed ubuntu-mate-18.04.2-beta1-desktop-armhf+raspi-ext4.img. When I try to sudo apt-get update I get the error

Temporary Failure resolving 'ports.ubuntu.com'

The raspberry pi has an ethernet connection to the internet. I have searched many times to find a solution but nothing seems to work. Is this because of the incompatibility of the Raspberry Pi 3 Model B? Should I upgrade to the Raspberry Pi 4? I don't want to do that if there is a problem with the OS? Please advise. Thank you in advance for your time.  This error is preventing me from updating and upgrading.  Please help me understand the problem and its resolution.

Comment: Generally, This OS is not completely stable. Recently, I installed and got some errors even on boot. Why have not you installed Raspbian?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not familiar with Raspian. I run Ubuntu on my VMware Workstation all the time. I want to get the point of running Intel's Movidius on my Raspberry pi 3.  I am seriously considering purchasing Raspberry Pi 4.  Are you telling me that you would recommend abandoning  Ubuntu-mate? After all of this wasted time, I slowing coming to this conclusion.

Comment: What is your key reason for choosing ubuntu-mate? Is that about the kernel?

Comment: Another question, are you running movidius myriad x ma2485?

Comment: It would be better if you ask this question on askubuntu.com.

Comment: Re: Reason for choosing ubuntu-mate:  I would prefer to run full up ubuntu 19.10 but it brought my pi3B to its knees.  I had run previous full versions of ubuntu without a problem.  Re:Are you running movidius myriad x ma2485.  I have the original movidius stick.  I am simple in the early part of setting it up when I ran into this OS problem.  Re: You would be better asking this on askubuntu.com.  Well when I posted this question on Stack Exchange they recommended I post to Raspberry PI.  I will try the Askubuntu.com  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the response. Yes, It's related to RaspberryPi but there is no answer yet. I think it's because of this part you said: `I have searched many times to find a solution but nothing seems to work.` All experts realized that you have done all the solutions.

Comment: My solution has been to switch to Rasparian.  Hopefully, Ubuntu will solve this problem.

Comment: Good luck. Be sure about the Raspbian version. You should Install the Raspbian buster.